# htaccess rewritecond for a search result

Tags: .htaccess, search, mod-rewrite

my friends.

Please, I have an issue with ReWriteCond. I would like to create friendly search results. I just do it with ReWriteRule, but I would like to do the reverse path.

This is working pretty good:
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)$ /index.php?p=search&query=$1 [L]

**But I would like to convert /index.php?p=search&query=$1 into search/query**

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt you want what you ask for... understand - if you want the to change the URL offered to the client in your application, you need to change it in your application then.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it is a search form. So, what should I put on the form action?
<form action="http://www.domain.com/index.php?p=search" method="get" name="search" id="search">...</form>

Comment: Hmm, solution would be to redirect the request to nice URL and then pass it to search script using `RewriteRule`s - OK, will answer in few seconds :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do redirect from "ugly" search form GET request to nice URL like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=search&query=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /search/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Then you have to make sure, the "nice" URL will reach your script like this:

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ index.php?query=%1&p=search [L]
```

Notice the different order of arguments / it prevents infinite loop

Comment: It's not working :/
After submit the form, I got this in the address box:
http://www.domain.com/search/myquery?p=search&query=myquery

Comment: @MarioLimaCavalcanti remove the `QSA` switch from your `RewriteRule` - it does append query string to the rewritten URL. You don't want it

Comment: Hmm.. But there's no QSA switch. I have only this on the top of the htaccess:

`RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: @MarioLimaCavalcanti then, add the question mark `?` at the end of redirect. See my updated answer

Comment: I don't know why, but it is working only when I click on the image button. If I press enter on the input text field, it does not work. Have you seen this before?

Comment: @MarioLimaCavalcanti it's possible the enter creates different URL than the click on image... what does your address bar show when you stay on the `ugly` URL?

Comment: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=search&query=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /search/%1? [R=301,L]`

Comment: With the above code, when I type the good address in the address bar it works, but when I use the search box, it shows the ugly address.

Comment: @MarioLimaCavalcanti you need to make sure, the *ugly* address does match with the rules above - so the part after `?` has exactly the form `p=search&query=sometext` and the part before `?` is `http://www.example.com/index.php` - example is of course your domain, but the rest has exactly match